# Should I use my mac or get a company new pc?

Tags: byod

I'm a software engineer and about to start a new job as software developer. 
I work with a Mac, and I really love it :) But, I will have to work with Windows. 
So I have 2 options:

1. install Windows on my Mac and use it for work (BYOD)
2. get a new laptop from work (probably a nice Dell computer)

It seems like option 2 is better, but... it s*cks to change everything :(
I worked as a freelancer and bought this Mac for work; I'm happy to work with it even if Windows is installed on it.

Comment: If you are happy with your computer as is and you don't have any problems with using a virtual windows environment then stick with what you got. I see no reason to buy another computer.

Comment: Option 1, you should AVOID using your personal computer at work since anything you create will be theres.

Comment: Is option 2 also BYOD? Or is it a work-only machine that they own?

Comment: "BYOD but you must install our OS of choice on it" sounds more like "we're cheap" than it does "we're hip".

Comment: Given that installing Windows on your Mac will wipe everything I don't see how much of a difference it makes whether you use your Mac with Windows or a computer they provide - either way you'd be running an OS with none of your stuff on it. Ask them to provide you with a good computer and use that instead, and keep your Mac for personal use only.

Comment: @AndréBorie  Not true.  You can run windows in a VM or dual boot.

Comment: Why Windows? While our standard desktop is Windows, and a few run Mac, the dev team uses Linux mostly, some Mac.

Comment: @DanNeely what I meant is that while booted into Windows it would essentially be a different machine with none of their Mac apps or settings. And I ruled out VMs as they would be a very bad idea security-wise (the host OS would have full control over the VM, so if the Mac has malware the VM would also be affected).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I assume they're developing with Microsoft technologies. .NET, ASP, etc...

Comment: @AndréBorie Maybe, or they have a corporate image.

Comment: I recently made the jump to a corporate Windows machine, about three months ago. I still much prefer OS X for my side projects, but the biggest thing I dislike about Windows is that Git takes forever and a day to do anything. Everything else is reasonably fast and not that horrible after you get used to it.

Comment: As a software engineer, it's easy to fall in love with a particular development environment or OS. As a *professional* software engineer, however, it behooves you to be comfortable and productive with different environments. (Unless of course you are indy who only every develops for a specific platform, and even then it's not bad thing to have a few strings to your bow).

Comment: @Undo it almost feels like the Windows NTFS isn't as performant as its Unix equivalents with regards to small files, as I too noticed a huge slowdown with Git, npm, pip, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're a company (wo)man now, so you will have to toe the company line.  That may mean using a windows based computer as your primary machine.

There are many benefits to the company for you to use the machine that they supply.  Such as:

1. Standard hardware and software load makes things easier for IT
2. Not mixing business and personal usage makes security more robust.
3. Better integration into networked based services.
4. Probably better insurance coverage for the hardware.

Unless you have a true BYOD policy then your desires really have no leverage here.  And going against the flow will cause some friction.

But I am confused as both of your options end up with you using windows.  So why not just go with the easiest option of a company supplied laptop?

I say this as someone who is writing this on a Mac Book Pro and has a client supplied Windows 10 based machine next to me, a different client's windows 7 based system behind that one and my own Windows 7 desktop to the other side of me and about 10 different Windows virtual machines tucked away on my Mac's hard drive.  My experience is that in general you get the best Windows user experience (as you can have) running Windows directly on the hardware it's designed for than running it on  Mac System via any sort of virtualized system.

---

My best option (and probably not something you can do) is to remote desktop into various windows systems from my Mac even though they are physically next to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I decide to use my mac, we will have BYOD policy. I agree with most of the things you said, it does seem like to wiser thing to do. I just really enjoy working on my computer ... thinking I can at least give it a go. I just didn't touch windows for a while, especially not for dev, so this bugs me

Comment: @Shaniqwa I think most of the enjoyment of using a Mac comes from the OS and the software. Running Windows on it will be much less enjoyable. (I'm saying that as a person who doesn't like either.)

Comment: @Shaniqwa how about you asking for a company-supplied Mac if you're more productive under macOS?

Comment: well, I decided to take a new company computer. like @Paŭlo Ebermann said the best part of mac is the OS and taking that out of the equation there is just not a good enough reason to use my own computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use your own machine for company work, what happens when you leave the company? What happens when the IT or Security departments want to scan your machine remotely? Who pays for the software on it?

Far too many unknowns and variables for me. Let the company supply the required hardware for you - and if you're used to a Mac, ask them for a Mac; they can only say no.

Answer (score 0):

Using your machine has a cost. It will depreciate faster, the risk of breaking something or getting robbed is greater.

Using a company machine means the depreciation, maintenance (and possibly insurance) costs are supported by your employer.

I would ask for a Mac on the grounds of being more productive ; if not possible, having another brand does not mean you have to use Windows; whilst our corporate image is Windows, the development team is using almost exclusively Linux, and I myself as the senior network/system administrator use a notebook with Mac, another Lenovo notebook with OpenBSD, and a PC with FreeBSD.

Some of us have Windows VMs for the odd task that require Windows in our private cloud, that we can use at work, or at home via VPN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did ask for a mac, but like I said we do have to work with windows, not sure exactly why but  the software is not cross-platform now and few things are coupled with window.

Comment: I did bring my Mac in my current job. After two years, they issued a Macbook for the whole team.

Comment: The Mac also lasted significantly less than my other Macbooks. You can put there a price tag of 2.5k at your cost easily.